# Подскажите редирект со всех страниц с цифрами в URL на такие же без цифр?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Подскажите редирект со страниц имеющих цифры в начале последней части URL на такой же URL без цифр?

Пример:

```
/category/category/130-page.html
/category/4-page.html
/50-page.html
```

перенаправить на:

```
/category/category2/page.html
/category/page.html
/page.html
```

Буду благодарен тому, кто подскажет решение через htaccess